# On the non-reversibility of the Heat semigroup

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $L$ a densely-defined self-adjoint operator bounded from below:
$$(Lx,x)\geq \omega (x,x), \;\; \omega\in \mathbb R $$
Then $-L$ generates a $c_0$ semigruop $\Phi(t):=\exp(-tL)$. If the eigenvalues of $L$ are $ \lambda_0\leq \lambda_1 \leq \cdots \leq \lambda_n \nearrow +\infty$, with eigenvectors $(u_k)_k$ (repeating the multiplicity), then the semigroup is:
$$ \Phi(t)u=\sum_{k\geq 0} (u,u_k)e^{-\lambda_kt}u_k $$
We can control very well this sum for $t>0$: for any natural $n$ and any $u\in H$, $\Phi(\cdot)u\in C^{\omega}((0,+\infty),\Gamma(L^n))$ is analytic, where $\Gamma(L^n)$ is the graph of $L^n$ with norm $||u||:=||u||_H+||L^nu||_H$.
In particular, this says that $\Phi(t):H\longrightarrow H$ is not surjective for any $t>0$.

Is $\Phi(t)$ injective?

If $E\subset H$ isn't the trivial subspace and $t>0$, is it true that $\Phi(t)(E)\varsubsetneq E$ and that $\Phi(t)|_E$ isn't injective?

If so, does it exist a way to measure how much non-injective and non-surjective is $\Phi(t)$ increasing $t$? (I think in physics, this is called entropy)

Comment: Every operator within an analytic $C_0$-semigroup is injective; this follows from the identity theorem for analytic functions.

Comment: Why does it work? Let $u(t)=\Phi(t)u_0$ and $v(t)=\Phi(t)v_0$. I don't see why having a $t_0>0$, $u(t_0)=v(t_0)$ implies that $\{t\in (0,+\infty) \; | \; u(t)=v(t) \}$ has an accumulation point.
Edit: I see, if $u(t_0)=v(t_0)$ then $u(t)=v(t)$ for $t>t_0$, as $u(t_0+h)=\Phi(h)u(t_0)=\Phi(h)v(t_0)=v(t_0+h)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The injectivity of $e^{-tL}$ is easy to see if you know the spectral theorem for self-adjoint operators: For every $u\in H$ there exists a Borel measure $\mu_u$ such that
$$
\langle u,f(L)u\rangle=\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(\lambda)\,d\mu_u(\lambda)
$$
for every bounded Borel function $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$.

Since $\lambda\mapsto e^{-t\lambda}$ is strictly positive and continuous, for all $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $e^{-t\lambda}\geq \epsilon$ for $\lambda\in [a,b)$. Thus, if $e^{-tL}u=0$, then
$$
0=\langle u,e^{-tL}u\rangle=\int e^{-t\lambda}\,d\mu_u(\lambda)\geq \epsilon \mu_u([a,b)).
$$
Hence $\mu_u=0$ and therefore also $0=\mu_u(\mathbb{R})=\|u\|^2$.